# custom post scheduler for drafts

Tags: posts, wp-update-post

I have a lot of posts everyday to publish. Now, I am thinking to schedule all those posts which I saved them as drafts. So, I tried to make a custom post scheduler. Here is what I tried,

```
$time = strtotime('+5 min');  

$args = array('post_type' => 'post','post_status' => 'draft');                  
$draft_posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach($draft_posts as $posts) {
$my_post = array(
      'ID'           => $posts->ID,
      'post_date'    => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time),
      'post_status'  => 'future');
$my_post->edit_date = true;
wp_update_post( $my_post );
$time += 5400;                                   // every 1.5 hr
}
```

As soon as I run this, all drafts are published instantly at same time, rather than an interval of 1.5 hr.
Can anyone please tell where is the problem?

Comment: There is option on post at the backend  wordpress dashboard from where you  can publish posts   the option is publish on  there you can set  the  date and time for the post to publish

Comment: I have around 100-125 posts, so it would be difficult for all to perform what you told.

Comment: you need to use jquery  to show posts after some time gape   but that is other way to delay the  post  post will publish at same time this way but not display on front end before the  given time  by jquery.

Comment: @Vickey you can schedule posts in this way. By setting a future date WordPress will label it 'scheduled' and it will be published after that date. busyjax, however, WordPress' "cron job" handling is not precise, and so batches of posts may be published together rather than every 90 minutes. That can be fixed using a genuine cron-job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're treating `$my_post` as an array, and then an object. Try moving 'edit_date' into the array.

Also keep in mind that 'post_date' should be in your blog's timezone. `date` will give the date-time in UTC timezone. See `date_i18n()` (codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n).

From what I can see, everything else is corret.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, after playing, I found that same you pointed about edit date.